# Create a registration form with a PayPal checkout fee?

Tags: forms, user-registration, paypal

My client is looking to start taking online registration for their many conventions and events. Previously they handled this all offline with PDF documents and in person payment. I'm looking for either a plugin or a detailed FAQ that will help me integrate an online registration plus payment system into their Wordpress site.

I'm open to both free and paid services. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

On a related note (just for some background on the scope of the project), ideally the user would have their own account on the Wordpress site. And they would register for one or multiple events at any given time throughout the year. This may or may not be difficult to implement. It's something they'd like to have, but if it's too hard I think we might just go without it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress + Gravity Forms is all you'll need for this project. [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) even has paypal integration. Set up a registration form, add on payment and you're ready to roll. They have detailed instructions and tutorials on how to set everything up and a very active forum if you run into any issues.

Comment: This looks like it has everything I need! Thank you!

Comment: please provide their Tutorial Link....:)